# Listing total number of features into an ArcGIS Online feature pop-up

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, feature-service, arcade

When configuring a feature service pop-up, how can I get the total number of features listed in the pop-up?  For example, I have a hydrant service.  When clicking on any hydrant, the pop-up would list the total amount of hydrants.  Is there a way to do this with arcade, other than creating an integer field and adding "1" to every row and using the sum?

Comment: [Count](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/data_functions/#count)?

Comment: That's it!  Thanks for the help!